# Cannot Deserialize Enum using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

The REST service returns this json string

```
"{\"UserProfile\":2,\"UserInfo\":0,\"Status\":1,\"Photo\":0,\"Video\":1,\"Comment\":0,\"ProfilePic\":0,\"Friends\":0,\"Tags\":2}"
```

And deserialize using this code:

```
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
    {
        T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
        System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        ms.Close();
        ms.Dispose();
        return obj;
    }  

Security sec = Deserialize<Security>(jsonresult);
```

Where:

```
[DataContract]
public class Security
{
    [DataMember]
    SecurityType UserProfile { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    SecurityType UserInfo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    SecurityType Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    SecurityType Photo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    SecurityType Video { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    SecurityType Comment { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    SecurityType ProfilePic { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    SecurityType Friends { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    SecurityType Tags { get; set; }
}
```

And the Enum:

```
[DataContract]
public enum SecurityType
{
    [EnumMember]
    Everyone,

    [EnumMember]
    FriendsOf,

    [EnumMember]
    Friends
}
```

After deserializing the jsonstring, it returns `Security` type with all property values equal to `Everyone` (which is equivalent to zero).
And looking at the `console.log`

```
$.post('@Url.Action("GetSecurityProfile", "Home")', { reload: reload }, function (data) {

    console.log(data);

    $('[data-security-profile] option').eq(data.UserProfile).attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('[data-security-info] option').eq(data.UserInfo).attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('[data-security-status] option').eq(data.Status).attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('[data-security-photos] option').eq(data.Photo).attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('[data-security-videos] option').eq(data.Video).attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('[data-security-comment] option').eq(data.Comment).attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('[data-security-profilepic] option').eq(data.ProfilePic).attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('[data-security-colleagues] option').eq(data.Friends).attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('[data-security-tags] option').eq(data.Tags).attr('selected', 'selected');

});
```

returns: `object{ }` (null value)
I can't figure out what wrong with the code. Please help.

Comment: The serializer is looking for enum fields named "0", "1", and "2"; not finding them, it is using the default value.  I'm not sure what the best solution is, I'm afraid.

Comment: Deserialize in C# code, why you are looking at js log?

Comment: Your code deserializes the json string just fine. I think some code you didn't post is responsible for losing your property values. My guess is that the problem is somewhere in your **GetSecurityProfile()** method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making properties of the **Security** class public:

```
[DataContract]
public class Security
{
    [DataMember]
    public SecurityType UserProfile { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SecurityType UserInfo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SecurityType Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SecurityType Photo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SecurityType Video { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SecurityType Comment { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SecurityType ProfilePic { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SecurityType Friends { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public SecurityType Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Oh my! I really didn't notice that. I think I'm overstress. Thank you!!